# SSSD new groups not added to user, "tsig verify failure ... update failed: REFUSED"?

Tags: active-directory, sssd

After adding a user to a group in Active Directory and looking for that group to appear with the user on a linux server linked to AD via SSSD, noticing that the group is not added to the user (even after restarting the `sssd` service).

Checking the SSSD daemon status, I see...

```bsh
[root@airflowetl ~]# systemctl status sssd
● sssd.service - System Security Services Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sssd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2020-01-21 15:54:14 HST; 9min ago
 Main PID: 87108 (sssd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/sssd.service
           ├─87108 /usr/sbin/sssd -i --logger=files
           ├─87111 /usr/libexec/sssd/sssd_be --domain co.local --uid 0 --gid 0 --logger=files
           ├─87112 /usr/libexec/sssd/sssd_nss --uid 0 --gid 0 --logger=files
           └─87113 /usr/libexec/sssd/sssd_pam --uid 0 --gid 0 --logger=files

Jan 21 15:54:14 airflowetl.co.local sssd_be[87111]: GSSAPI client step 1
Jan 21 15:54:14 airflowetl.co.local sssd_be[87111]: GSSAPI client step 1
Jan 21 15:54:14 airflowetl.co.local sssd_be[87111]: GSSAPI client step 1
Jan 21 15:54:14 airflowetl.co.local sssd_be[87111]: GSSAPI client step 2
Jan 21 15:54:14 airflowetl.co.local systemd[1]: Started System Security Services Daemon.
Jan 21 15:54:15 airflowetl.co.local sssd[87108]: ; TSIG error with server: tsig verify failure
Jan 21 15:54:15 airflowetl.co.local sssd[87108]: update failed: REFUSED
Jan 21 15:54:15 airflowetl.co.local sssd[87108]: ; TSIG error with server: tsig verify failure
Jan 21 15:54:15 airflowetl.co.local sssd[87108]: update failed: REFUSED
Jan 21 16:00:40 airflowetl.co.local sssd[be[co.local]][87111]: Warning: user would have been denie....
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

I'm guessing the

> update failed: REFUSED

part is the problem here.

For further reference, the server's `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf` file looks like...

```
[root@airflowetl ~]# cat /etc/sssd/sssd.conf

[sssd]
domains = co.local
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam

[domain/co.local]
ad_domain = co.local
krb5_realm = CO.LOCAL
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-samba
cache_credentials = False
id_provider = ad
krb5_store_password_if_offline = False
default_shell = /bin/bash
ldap_id_mapping = False
ldap_user_uid_number = uidNumber
ldap_user_gid_number = gidNumber
ldap_group_gid_number = gidNumber
use_fully_qualified_names = False
fallback_homedir = /home/%u
access_provider = ad
default_domain_suffix = co.local
```

Some OS info:

```
[root@airflowetl ~]# lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch:cxx-4.1-amd64:cxx-4.1-noarch:desktop-4.1-amd64:desktop-4.1-noarch:languages-4.1-amd64:languages-4.1-noarch:printing-4.1-amd64:printing-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)
Release:        7.4.1708
Codename:       Core
```

Note that we recently changed our primary DNS server and the `/etc/resolv.conf` file does reflect these changes, but I suspect that this is very related.

Does anyone with more experience with SSSD have any debugging tips or know what could be going wrong here?

---

UPDATE:

after checking a server where the DNS was not updated (rather the server is using the secondary DNS), when initially checking sssd status I see

```bsh
[root@hwdatalake datalake]# systemctl status sssd
● sssd.service - System Security Services Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sssd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-01-22 12:55:22 HST; 21h ago
 Main PID: 95837 (sssd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/sssd.service
           ├─95837 /usr/sbin/sssd -i --logger=files
           ├─95838 /usr/libexec/sssd/sssd_be --domain co.local --uid 0 --gid 0 --logger=files
           ├─95839 /usr/libexec/sssd/sssd_nss --uid 0 --gid 0 --logger=files
           └─95840 /usr/libexec/sssd/sssd_pam --uid 0 --gid 0 --logger=files

Jan 22 12:55:17 hwdatalake.co.local systemd[1]: Starting System Security Services Daemon...
Jan 22 12:55:17 hwdatalake.co.local sssd[95837]: Starting up
Jan 22 12:55:17 hwdatalake.co.local sssd[be[co.local]][95838]: Starting up
Jan 22 12:55:22 hwdatalake.co.local sssd[pam][95840]: Starting up
Jan 22 12:55:22 hwdatalake.co.local sssd[nss][95839]: Starting up
Jan 22 12:55:22 hwdatalake.co.local systemd[1]: Started System Security Services Daemon.
Jan 22 12:56:50 hwdatalake.co.local sssd[be[co.local]][95838]: Backend is offline
```

then after restarting the service, see

```bsh
[root@hwdatalake datalake]# systemctl status sssd
● sssd.service - System Security Services Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sssd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-01-23 10:19:05 HST; 15s ago
 Main PID: 98653 (sssd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/sssd.service
           ├─98653 /usr/sbin/sssd -i --logger=files
           ├─98654 /usr/libexec/sssd/sssd_be --domain co.local --uid 0 --gid 0 --logger=files
           ├─98655 /usr/libexec/sssd/sssd_nss --uid 0 --gid 0 --logger=files
           └─98656 /usr/libexec/sssd/sssd_pam --uid 0 --gid 0 --logger=files

Jan 23 10:18:54 hwdatalake.co.local systemd[1]: Starting System Security Services Daemon...
Jan 23 10:18:54 hwdatalake.co.local sssd[98653]: Starting up
Jan 23 10:18:54 hwdatalake.co.local sssd[be[co.local]][98654]: Starting up
Jan 23 10:19:05 hwdatalake.co.local sssd[nss][98655]: Starting up
Jan 23 10:19:05 hwdatalake.co.local sssd[pam][98656]: Starting up
Jan 23 10:19:05 hwdatalake.co.local systemd[1]: Started System Security Services Daemon.
```

and checking the groups for a given user shows the updated groups being correctly associated with the user. Yet even then, after some time, when checking again I see that the

> Jan 23 10:20:33 hwdatalake.co.local sssd[be[co.local]][98654]: Backend is offline

error is back and at some time *even later* checking the groups for the user is **back to the old settings**.